# Exoplayer 2.7.0 , 2.3.1 version conflicts

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

Currently I am using `Exoplayer` library with version 2.3.1. I want to include `Exoplayer` version 2.7.0 in same project. How can we do that without conflict?

I tried to include 2.7.1 and 2.3.1 so it's taking updated version by default.

Answer (score 1):

> "I tried to include 2.7.1 and 2.3.1 so it's taking updated version by default."

I would suggest just trying to change your app's dependency on Exoplayer 2.3.1 to 2.7.0.

- If you don't get compilation / build errors ... and your code works, then you have answered your question.
- If you get compilation errors, examine them carefully, look at the Exoplayer javadocs and release notes, and figure out what changes you need to make your code to use the newer APIs.

If updating your code proves intractable (i.e. too much work), you may well be stuck.  However, it shouldn't be.  It is unlikely that the authors of the library would produce new releases that are so incompatible that upgrading is intractable ... for a skilled engineer.  What is more, the [Exoplayer site](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) says:

> "Unlike the MediaPlayer API, ExoPlayer is easy to customize and extend, *and can be updated through Play Store application updates*."

(emphasis added) so they clearly *intend* upgrading to be simple.

Getting an application to use two separate versions of some library *at the same time* is unlikely to work.  And it is unlikely that you want your application to have two distinct media player UIs ...